# Ordering with list of columns is not working as expected

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using a ordering function inside my MLRanker code

```
    ranking.rdd
      .keyBy(t => {
        keyBySeq(t)
      })
      .topByKey(k)(orderByColumns)
      .flatMap(_._2)
      .toDS
```

Ordering function which works as expected

```
implicit val orderByColumns: Ordering[ranking] = Ordering.by(
      e => (e.name, e.rank, e.score)
    )
```

Ordering function which doesn't work as expected

```
 def orderBySeq(e: Ranking): Seq[Any] = {
    var listOfKeys = new ListBuffer[Any]()
    listOfKeys += e.name
    listOfKeys += e.rank
    listOfKeys += e.score
    listOfKeys.seq
  }

implicit val orderByColumns: Ordering[ranking] = Ordering.by(
      e => orderBySeq(e)
    )
```

Can someone let me know how I can pass a sequence of values to the ordering function?

Answer (score 0):

So you already have an `Ordering[Ranking]` and wish to add another one that uses some iterable based ordering ?

This should work directly because of existing ordering implicits:

```scala
implicit val orderByColumns: Ordering[Ranking] =
  Ordering.by(e => Iterable(e.name, e.rank, e.score))
```

`Ordering` has an implicit conversion from any `Ordering[T]` to `Ordering[Iterable[T]]`.

**UPDATE:**
so you're `Ranking` class is something like:

```scala
case class Ranking(name: String, rank: Double, score: Boolean)
```

and if you do:

```scala
implicit val orderByColumns: Ordering[Ranking] =
  Ordering.by(e => Iterable(e.name, e.rank, e.score))
```

then `.. Iterable(e.name, e.rank, e.score)` gets resolved to type `Iterable[Any]` and for this to work we need an `Ordering[Any]`.

We don't have that. Try making everything a string:

```scala
implicit val orderByColumns: Ordering[Ranking] =
  Ordering.by(e => Iterable(e.name, e.rank, e.score).map(_.toString))
```

and if you're working with a lot of fields you could even do:

```scala
implicit val orderByColumns: Ordering[Ranking] =
  Ordering.by(e => e.productIterator.map(_.toString).toIterable)
```

However I would question the necessity.
Why is this not enough ?

```scala
implicit val orderByColumns: Ordering[ranking] = 
  Ordering.by(e => (e.name, e.rank, e.score))
```

Comment: I get this error when I try the above code
```No implicit Ordering defined for Iterable[Any].
    implicit val orderByColumns: Ordering[Ranking] = Ordering.by(```

Comment: Share an example on scastie.
This works: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ClvgEBNiS7y8pS2EdPbDKQ

Please share the `Ranking` class as well.

Comment: I meant something like this https://scastie.scala-lang.org/tSyJwtOQSQeHsitMavilGw

Comment: the example I gave looks good enough?

Comment: I've updated my main response